# Password hashing: Is this a way to avoid collisions?

Tags: security, hash, passwords

I was thinking about using 2 keys for hashing each user password, obtaining 2 different hashes. This way, it would be (almost?) impossible to find a password that works, other than the actual password.

Is that right? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An important rule to learn is "never try to invent your own cryptography".  You are just wasting time at best and introducing security holes at worst.

If you are unsure whether you are an exception to this rule, then you are not an exception to this rule.

The designers of cryptographic hashes already worried about collisions so you do not have to.  Just pick one (SHA-256 is a fine choice) and focus your efforts on the rest of your application.

Comment: Note that while SHA-256 is strong enough as far as size and cryptographic strength is concerned, it isn't good for password hashing in its plain form. You need a slow, salted scheme, such as PBKDF2, scrypt or bcrypt.

Answer (score 6):

You might use SHA256 as a hashing algorithm instead. No collisions were found to date, and it's highly unlikely to see any collisions on *passwords* in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use a longer hash. SHA-512, for example, is 512 bits, and (assuming it's uniform) far, far less likely to clash as SHA-256. But personally, I wouldn't worry about it. Most passwords themselves are less than 32 bytes (256 bits), and so should have an extremely low probability of clashing with SHA-256.

Comment: I am not an expert but I am pretty sure doubling the bit length makes a class only "has as likely to clash".

Comment: @cdiggins: Can you elaborate please? I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Assuming the best you can do to look for a collision is to guess randomly (which is true for SHA-N as far as anybody knows), the odds of picking an x whose hash collides with that of a given y is 1/2^256 for SHA-256 and 1/2^512 for SHA-512.  The latter is much, much less than 1/2 of the former.  Neither one is going to happen, though, in the sense that you are not going to win first place in the lottery every day for the rest of your life.

Comment: @Nemo: Ah, you're absolutely right. Never do maths at 1am. I'll edit the question to reflect that now.